# Excel VBA set print area to last row with data

Tags: excel, vba, printing, area

I have an Excel table with a sheet "CR" where columns A to K are filled, with the first row being a header row.

Rows 1-1000 are formatted (borders) and column A contains a formula to autonumber the rows when data in column F is entered.

Sheet "CR" is protected to prevent users from entering data in column A (locked).

Using the Workbook_BeforePrint function, I'm trying to set the print area to columns A to K and to the last row of column A that contains a number.

My code (in object 'ThisWorkbook') is as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CR")

' find the last row with data in column A
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ws.Range("A1:K" & lastRow).Address
End Sub
```

However, when I click File -> Print, the range of columns A to K up to row 1000 is displayed instead of only the rows that have a number in column A. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

To:

```
lastRow = [LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A65536<>""),ROW(A1:A65536))]
```

Comment: I've updated the code with your change but it still shows everything.

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed above, assuming your data isn't bigger than 65536 rows.

Comment: Thanks, that works (also in print preview when clicking File->Print)

Answer (score 0):

`.End(...)` will act like ctrl + arrow-key. if the cell has a formula (which looks empty due to the formula, then it will still stop there... another way would be the use of evaluate (if you do not want to loop) like this:

```
lastRow = .Evaluate("MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(1E+100,A:A,1),0),IFERROR(MATCH(""zzz"",A:A,1),0))")
```

This will give the last row (which has a value in column A).

Also check if there are hidden values (looking empty due number format or having characters you can't see directly. Try to go below row 1000 in column A (select a cell after A1000 in column A) and hit ctrl+up to validate where it stops (and why).

**EDIT:**
*(regarding your comment)*

`""` still leads to a "stop" for the `.End(...)`-command. So either use my formula, translate the formula into vba or loop the cells it get the last value. Also `Find` is a good tool (if not doing it over and over for countless times).

```
lastRow = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("B1"), xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
```

Comment: Indeed, if I select cell A1010 and hit Ctrl+up, cell A1000 is selected which contains the formula: =IF(F1000<>"",ROW()-1,"") but does not have a value in it. If I delete the formula in cells A990 till A1000 and hit Ctrl+up, cell A989 is selected => it has definitely to do with the formula in the cells and not with the formatting (borders).

Comment: @Antoon please see my edit... looking for anything just by values also skips the formula cells if they output `""`

Comment: When I try to print with the code 'lastRow = .Evaluate("MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(1E+100,A:A,1),0),IFERROR(MATCH(""zzz"",A:A,1),0))")' it gives me a compile error: invalid or unqualified reference and it highlights .Evaluate

Comment: `lastRow = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("B1"), xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row` gives me a compile error: invalid or unqualified reference and it highlights .Range

Comment: that is confusing, as i have tested all the code and none got me any error... well, you got a workable solution, so there should be no reason for me to overanalyze the problem